# Enter four coordinates and get a polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, qgis-plugins, coordinates

Is it possible to enter four coordinates for getting a polygon?

I have to clip lots of exact rectangles and I was just wondering whether you know a plugin

Answer (score 3):

Please check out the [QuickWKT plugin](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/QuickWKT/).

> Description: Quick WKT/WKB viewer, this Qgis Plugin opens a dialog
>   where the user can paste (E)WKT and WKB code and see it on the map.
>   Pasted data are stored in a temporay (memory) layer and are completely
>   lost when the user quits QGIS.

You'll have to save the layer as shape file afterwards or you'll lose them. You'll also need to specify your coordinates in the [WKT format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text), for example:

> "POLYGON((571178 6337246,571178 6402217,598061 6402217,598061
>   6337246,571178 6337246))"

The first and last coordinates have to be the same, otherwise it will result in a line. Good luck :)

[image]