# Box cropping shapefile based on particular latitude and longitude using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, clip

I have a shapefile and I need to crop/clip it based on a rectangle of particular latitude and longitude using QGIS.

If it is possible, how do I do that?

[image]

Comment: @vinayan no, it use 2 shapefile in that question, I only have one.

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to clarify that your requirement is to be able to specify min/max lats and longs to form a rectangle that is to be used to clip a shapefile, please?

Comment: This Q&A looks like it may also be helpful to you: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34202/enter-4-coordinates-and-get-a-polygon-qgis

Answer (score 3):

You can create another layer, draw a box by your coordinates and follow the already referenced answer [How to crop Shapefiles in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37226/how-to-crop-shapefiles-in-qgis). I would myself use ogr2ogr with the -spat parameter. If you want also to clip the selected features with the selection box use `-clipsrc [xmin ymin xmax ymax]|`

http://gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html

QGIS Processing toolbox has a GDAL raster tool in "GDAL/OGR - Extraction - Clip raster by extent". Similar tool for vectors would be generally useful. Perhaps you could make a QGIS feature request "Add a new GDAL/ORG tool: Clip vector layer by extent".